# Вывести желаемый текст из строки в bash

Tags: bash

Мне необходимо вывести текст без тегов, из `html` с помощью `bash`. 
К примеру у меня есть:

```
<body> Test <a href=”google.com”>Google</a></body>
```

вывод:
`Test Google`

Comment: `sed -r 's|<[^>]+>||g' <<< "<body> Test <a href=”google.com”>Google</a></body>" ` Попробуйте

Comment: Огромное спасибо !)

Comment: @PotroNik  Оформите в качестве ответа?

Comment: Я бы парсил выхлоп `elinks -dump`. Не чистый bash, но всё же.

Comment: Надо парсить DOM и проходить все узлы. Все регулярные выражения не могут обработать HTML. Подробности тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2511795

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed -r 's|<[^>]+>||g' /путь к файлу
```

Ключ `-r` - расширенные регулярные выражения

`s|<[^>]+>||g` - шаблон замены, в котором мы ищем любое количество символов после `<` кроме символа `>` и соответственно закрывающий символ тега `>` и заменяем их на пустоту.

---

Команду можно выполнять через "пайп", либо производить сразу замену в файле добавив ключ `-i`
стоит обратить внимание что ключи `-i -r` желательно указывать отдельно, на некоторых версиях sed написание ключей `-ir` не открывает расширенных возможностей регулярных выражений.

---

Так же стоит заметить что команда может сработать не так как предполагается, в случае когда на одной стоке тег открывается, а на другой закрывается.